# Looking for Free Api's for Address auto completion and Geocoding

Tags: flutter, dart, open-source, geocoding, flutterflow

I am working on a flutter application for both ios and android using Flutter Flow. I am working on a feature where users can search for listings in a specific area(Requires Address) or nearby(Using Mobile GPS).

I am looking for any api's or libraries which can help me achieve any or all of the following. At the moment I can't invest money into using Google Maps Api's or any other's that involve money.

1. Help users with suggestions as user types in the address into a search box.
2. Once an address is selected from suggestions, Convert the specific address to Latitude and Longitude.
3. OR Show a static map to user and allow user to place a marker on the map which can return coordinates and I can use them to list nearby listings.

Can anyone suggest any api's or services I can use for the above use cases? I know there's always a price associated with such huge implementations. But looking for suggestions from community and combine them into workable solution.

Thanks in advance.

Looked at Google maps Apis, Open Cage api's.

Comment: Open Street Map has a number of offerings.  Not sure about autocomplete, but they do have turn-by-turn directions, for example, and pretty decent searches.

Comment: Requesting for suggestions regarding libraries, API, etc is considered Off Topic for StackOverFlow policies

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Thank you for the suggestion. I tried looking at Open Street Api, but not a best fit for my use case.

Comment: @Anvith I'm a moderator here. I recommend you to read the on topic policies: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and exactly the point regarding "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource"

Answer (score 1):

I found one API service which gives free auto completed address APIs ( There are some limitations of-course). This tool is **Radar**. You will find auto complete API from [here](https://radar.com/documentation/api#autocomplete). It may be not accurate as Google Place API.

Comment: Please, don't give answers regarding off topic questions. Asking for libraries, API, etc is considered off topic for StackOverFlow policies